# conformal mapping onto right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a conformal map of $D:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$ and $|z+i|<\sqrt{2}\}$ onto the right half plane.

My idea was to use $$f(z)=\frac{z+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{z-\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}$$

To map $D$ to a sector and then use $$g(z)=z^{\beta}$$

for an appropriate value of $\beta$ to map the sector to the half plane. What technique should I use to find $\beta$? Since $f$ is conformal there must be a way to get the angle of the sector from $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about $\pm\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}$? It looks like you've forgotten to square the radius and it should be $\pm 1$ instead.

From geometric grounds it should be clear that the two corners of $D$ have internal angles of 90° -- draw a sketch if this is unclear.

The mapping $z\mapsto \frac{z+1}{z-1}$ moves the left corner to $0$,, and since it is conformal in the vicinity of $z=-1$, the inner angle of the corner of $f(D)$ is still 90°.

In order to spread this sector out to a half-plane you need to double the angle, so your $\beta$ must be 2.

Comment: Nice solution. You are correct I was making a bunch of goofy mistakes. I had to go outside and exercise for awhile.